# Hideshow with python hiding only one part

Tags: package, code-folding

I've been trying to use [Hide Show](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow) package in emacs. I encountered a problem when using python. Let's say I have the following code:

[image: Test code]

When I have hit the command `hs-hide-level`. This is the result.

[image: Result]

Which is not correct since I'm looking for this:

[image: What I'm looking for]

So, apparently there's a bug in the code which provokes that the folding is being done only in the impair methods (for some reason), but I'm asking here for a workaround if anyone has encountered the same problem.

I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 under ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: And if anyone could be kind to tell me where to report the bug, it would be nice too, because there's no github's repository for this apparently.

Comment: As `hide-show` is part of Emacs, you must hand in an Emacs bug, preferably by using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a conf that do what you want:

```el
    (defun py-outline-level ()
      (let (buffer-invisibility-spec)
        (save-excursion
          (skip-chars-forward "\t ")
          (current-column))))
    (defun hide-body-recenter ()
      (interactive)
      (hide-body)
      (recenter))
    (defun my-pythonFold-hook ()
      (setq outline-regexp "[^ \t\n]\\|[ \t]*\\(def[ \t]+\\|class[ \t]+\\)")
      (setq outline-level 'py-outline-level)
      (outline-minor-mode t)
      (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-<kp-subtract>") 'hide-body-recenter)
      (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-<kp-add>") 'show-all)
      (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-S-<kp-subtract>") 'hide-subtree)
      (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-S-<kp-add>") 'show-subtree))
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-pythonFold-hook)
```

Then you can use C-+, C--, C-S-+, and C-S-- (numeric keypad)

Comment: I'm only using one little part of your code but as you say, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks ;)

Comment: another comment years appart, do you know how to add docstrings so they hide at the same time?